# Python BeautifulSoup on javascript tables with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used to have a python script that pulled data from the below table properly using Mechanize and BeautifulSoup.  However, this site has recently changed the encoding of the table to javascript, and I'm having trouble working with it because there are multiple pages to the table.

http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2011&month=0&season1=&ind=0&team=25&players=0

For example, in the link above, how could I grab the data from both page 1 and page 2 of the table? FWIW, The URL doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to run a headless browser e.g [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/) which understands all the intricacies of JavaScript, DOM etc but you will have to write your code in Javascript, benefit is that you can do whatever you want, parsing html using BeautifulSoup is cool for a while but is headache in long term. So why scrape when you can access the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize doesn't handle javascript.

You could observe what requests are made when you click the button (using Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome). Than try to reverse engineer the javascript running behind the page and try to do the similar thing using your python code, for that take a look at [Spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/) or

Try using `Selenium`.

> Selenium is a funcitonal testing framework which automates the browser to perform certain operations which in turn test the underlying actions of your code